# Can't get the templates to load in Django

Tags: django, mezzanine

**This is my setting:**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "django.core.context_processors.debug",
                "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
                "django.core.context_processors.static",
                "django.core.context_processors.media",
                "django.core.context_processors.request",
                "django.core.context_processors.tz",
                "mezzanine.conf.context_processors.settings",
                "mezzanine.pages.context_processors.page",
                "main.context_processors.global_settings",
            ],
            "builtins": [
                "mezzanine.template.loader_tags",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**I have the structure:**

```
project_name
- theme_1
- theme_2
- templates
-- theme_1
--- index.html
--- base.html
-- theme_2
--- index.html
--- base.html
- static
- project_name
```

**I did also try to add the structure inside the apps/themes:**

```
theme_1
- templates
-- theme_1
--- base.html
theme_2
- templates
-- theme_2
--- base.html
```

What could be the issue here? Why do not my template files load? I only get the default Mezzanine project templates and static files to load.

Comment: Show a view that calls on one of your templates.  Have you read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#configuration

Comment: The first structure is definitely wrong (unless you add a dir to `DIRS`). The second structure should work, but we need to see your views.

Comment: In the second structure: app names missing in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: set `'DIRS': [],`  to contain the path to your `templates` directory, that is what django's looking for